# Remap Escape = Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock = Ctrl_L and Ctrl_L = Caps_Lock

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I would like to swap keys using xmodmap as in the title. I would like the useless capslock to be bind to the escape key, the escape function to be bind to the bottom left control to and the ctrl to be bind to the caps lock. I have tried this

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L

keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L 
keysym Control_L = Escape
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock

add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```

but it doesn't work, I am not sure why.